Ignore a location segment in Ngnix to serve static files
My application generates static URLs such as:
/nhub/public/static/A8Ec-8B33/css/styles.css
/nhub/public/static/A8Ec-8B33/favicon.ico

After an update to the app, it generates same URLs as:
/nhub/public/static/X53L-SbTy/css/styles.css
/nhub/public/static/X53L-SbTy/favicon.ico

The segments A8Ec-8B33 and X53L-SbTy were uniquely generated by the app for each version.
For both cases, I want NGINX to point to the same underlying files at:
D:\sitenhub\sitestatic\css\styles.css
D:\sitenhub\sitestatic\favicon.ico

I tried:
location ~ ^/nhub/public/static/[^\/]+/ {
  alias D:/sitenhub/sitestatic/;
}

but getting 403 forbidden for above examples. Would appreciate help.

What is the root directive value setting?

@DanilaVershinin I found out that Regex matches need capturing groups that need to be referred to in alias. I got it working for both Nginx and Apache, see my answer. But thank you.

From NGINX documentation:

If alias is used inside a location defined with a regular expression then such regular expression should contain captures and alias should refer to these captures (0.7.40), for example:

location ~ ^/users/(.+\.(?:gif|jpe?g|png))$ {
    alias /data/w3/images/$1;
}

So finally this worked for me:
# Nginx
location ~ ^/nhub/public/static/[^/]+/(.*)$ {
  alias D:/sitenhub/sitestatic/$1;
}

# Apache HTTPD
AliasMatch "^/nhub/public/static/[^/]+/(.*)$" "D:/sitenhub/sitestatic/$1"

([^/]+ matches at least one char that is not /, (.*) is a capturing group that matches zero or more any characters, this capturing group is referred to by $1 in the alias)
